# Save Id from PHP database as variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, offline

I'm working on a offine web application. But on a certain point it need to receive data from a sql database. This is done with an iframe. However the PHP files print all the data available. Every row of data has a workID, and i want them to be clickable. When you click on the work ID i need to save the work ID as variable so i can use the work ID through my whole application.
For example: I choose 1 work ID. Onclick the work ID is written in my header on every page.
I don't know if this can be done with cookies or just a javascript function on the main page.

See the following code:

```
<?php

$result=mysql_query("SELECT workid,problem,request FROM workreport ORDER BY workid;");

$i=0;
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    if($i>0)
    {
        echo "<tr valign=bottom>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr valign=center>";
    echo "<td class=tabval></td>";
    echo "<td class=tabval><b>".htmlspecialchars($row['workid'])."</b></button></td>";
    echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['problem'])."&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['request'])."&nbsp;</td>";
    $i++;
}?>
```

PHP is loaded in an iframe. So i prefer to create the function to save the work id on my main page.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/receive.php" width="400" height="300" style="border:none;"> </iframe>
```

Hope you can help me! thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use cookies or localStorage

Comment: The best advice i can give you is this: learn updated technologies. First, PHP's mysql_ library is deprecated and it's going to be dropped altogether soon: replace it with PDO. Second, iframes are generally considered a bad practice: you can replace them with AJAX most of the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, using javascript and PHP: 
**PHP**:

```
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
if($i>0)
{
    echo "<tr valign=bottom>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr valign=center>";
echo "<td class=tabval></td>";
echo "<td class=tabval><button id=\"saveid\"><b>".htmlspecialchars($row['workid'])."</b></button></td>";
echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['problem'])."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class=tabval>".htmlspecialchars($row['request'])."&nbsp;</td>";
$i++;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('saveid').onclick = function () {
   var id = this.innerHTML;
   document.cookie = "saveid=" + id + ", expires=Monday, 04-Apr-2020 05:00:00 GMT";
   alert('Cookie saved!');
  }
}
```

Okay, the cookie is now saved. You can access it in PHP using $_COOKIE['saveid'].

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does work at some point. It can alert the ID of my first item. However it does nothing on the other rows inserted in my database.
And as i launch the PHP file in an i frame i cannot call the cookie (tryed with local storage as well) in on other pages.
Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: If you include the php file before you click #saveid, then it does not work... Ups, my error! I setted cookie name to 'id'. I fixed it, now it should work!

Comment: Still not working. Same problem it can only save the first data row.

Comment: problem solved! i used <a href=\"#\" class=\"saveid\"> instead of the button and jquery to find the class. Multiple buttons with the same id can't call the same function. Thank you very much!